# How to update specific Grails domain class properties?

Tags: java, grails

I am trying to update the password of currently logged in user. But it shows me null point exception.

Profile Controller:

```
def doPasswordChange(){
    def response = authenticationService.getMember()
    if (!response) {
        flash.message = AppUtil.infoMessage(g.message(code: "invalid.entity"), false)
        redirect(controller: "profile", action: "changePassword")
    } else {
        response = profileService.doPasswordChange(response, params)
        if (!response.isSuccess) {
            flash.redirectParams = response.model
            flash.message = AppUtil.infoMessage(g.message(code: "password.not.change"), false)
            redirect(controller: "profile", action: "changePassword")
        } else {
            flash.message = AppUtil.infoMessage(g.message(code: "updated"))
            redirect(controller: "profile", action: "index")
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileService:

```
def doPasswordChange(Member member, GrailsParameterMap params){
    params.password = params.password.encodeAsMD5()
    params.newPassword = params.newPassword.encodeAsMD5()
    params.confirmPassword = params.confirmPassword.encodeAsMD5()
    def response = AppUtil.saveResponse(false, member)
    if(member.password==params.password && params.confirmPassword==params.newPassword){
        member.password = params.newPassword     //this line is gives me  null point exception
        if(member.validate()){
            log.warn myDomainObj.errors.allErrors.join(' \n')
            member.save(flush: true, failOnError:true)
            response.isSuccess = true
        }
        else println("ok")
    }
    return response
}
```

Gives me this error :

> 2019-07-09 01:55:04.284 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-8]
>   o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NullPointerException
>   occurred when processing request: [POST] /profile/doPasswordChange -
>   parameters: password: abcdqrty newPassword: 12345 confirmPassword:
>   12345 login: Change Password Stacktrace follows:
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null     at
>   org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
>     at
>   org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.getModifiedPropertiesWithAutotimestamp(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:206)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.synchronizeHibernateState(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:188)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:249)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:244)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:118)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.flushSession(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:289)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:254)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:299)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:117)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:251)
>     at
>   org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:168)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
>     at
>   com.santho.bitmascot.ProfileService.doPasswordChange(ProfileService.groovy:15)
>     at
>   com.santho.bitmascot.ProfileController.doPasswordChange(ProfileController.groovy:24)
>     ... 14 common frames omitted

I tried only assigning a new value to other member class properties. Same error. 
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

in View

add property useToken="true" in  form

```
<g:form  name="applyForm" useToken="true">
  //ur code
  </g:form>
```

in controller

put ur action's code  into withForm{}

```
withForm {
//ur origin code in action
}.invalidToken {
//what to do when token invalidate
        }
```